# Assume an odd perfect number exists could be it written as $x^3+y^3+z^3$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, perfect-numbers

Touchard $(1953)$ proved that an odd perfect number, if it exists, must be of the form $12k+1$ or $ 36k+9$(Holdener  $2002 $) , A necessary condition for any number to be written as a cubic sum  $x^3+y^3+z^3$  is that number can't be $4$ or $5 \bmod 9$,one can think about $12k+1$ which is $4$ or $7$ mod $9$ then we can't say anything since we have the remainder is equal to $4$, but if it is of the form $ 36k+9$ this is conguent $1 \bmod 4$, Which is impossible ? , Now I ask Assume an odd perfect exists could be it written as $x^3+y^3+z^3$ ?

Comment: Bakir Farhi conjectures in the arXiv preprint titled [On the representation of an even perfect number as the sum of a limited number of cubes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.07322) that any **even perfect number**, other than $6$, can be written as the sum of only $3$ cubes of natural numbers.  Note that
$$28 = 0^3 + 1^3 + 3^3.$$
I will think more about the *modular considerations* that you espouse in trying to answer the question of whether an **odd perfect number** could be written as
$$x^3 + y^3 + z^3,$$
assuming it exists.

Comment: An upvote for now, @zeraouliarafik =)